# Is it okay to rely on the MD5 check sum based on the first 1024 bytes of a file for file duplicate comparison?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm creating a Python program that determines if a file from a website is already available on my computer (already downloaded), and my way of determining that is I get the MD5 of that file from the website, then compare it with the MD5 records of files stored in my database. My concern is this procedure will be very slow if tried on large files on a website; so is it safe to only compute the first 1024 bytes of that file on the web to determine if its a duplicate file or not? Or do you have some more simple elegant or faster way to do this in Python.

Comment: Comparing only the first 1024 bytes of a file means that any change to the 1025th byte or 1026th byte (etc.) will not be detected.  Does this sound robust?

Comment: no. it's not safe. consider a large gif (say, 10,000 x 10,000) where only the very last pixel is different. two different files, but the first 1024 bytes of both files are going to be identical, producing the same md5 hash, and therefore a false positive in your dupe checker.. md5() is a pretty fast hash. the time to hash a multi-meg file is NOT that significant

Comment: Try SHA-1 on the contents of the file.Something git does

Comment: @ScroojMcDuck: How does that help matters?

Comment: Why don't you take 1024 bytes every megabyte(or more/less depending on your needs) and compute the md5 of this? This will surely be more robust than taking only the first 1024 bytes, and you have a chance to detect changes in different positions on the file. Also when you find an hash match you should download the whole files and do further checks. This wont happen many times, so it shouldn't consume all your bandwidth like doing this for every file. BTW: I'd also check the exact file size, which is a simple way of checking whether two files are not duplicates.

Comment: Many servers won't allow you to selectively download only selected parts of a file.

Answer (score 1):

No; it is not uncommon for web pages to be identical in the first 1024 bytes.  For example, many complex sites have JavaScript, CSS, and boilerplate HTML at the top of the HTML file which far exceed the 1024 bytes you have budgeted.

Some experimentation with real-life data may reveal a reasonable buffer, but there is simply no way to predict that two otherwise identical files will not differ in the last byte other than by doing a full-file comparison.  But if your input data says otherwise (perhaps what you are comparing are individual tweets, for example?) then by all means go by that.

Many web servers will include a server-generated `ETag:` header which might be useful, but it's not standardized, and for all you know, they could easily be spoofing you.

Comment: im checking actually for binary file duplications like PDF, or AVI, which commonly is quite big,and if i will check for the whole file's md5 it will be the same as like downloading that whole file, which is not an option as my internet connection is very slow. perhaps increasing 1024 to a fairly high number will lessen the chance of having duplicates?i really need to get this efficient as possible cause this will be use in a loop for my web scraping experiment. thanks for all your responses.